# Saving audio bytes transmitted over websocket connection in flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, websocket

Problem background: Develop an application that can open websocket for audio streaming and make connection to client to output speech to text conversion when audio bytes are transmitted over websocket.

Have a python flask backend and javascript frontend to develop an independent websocket application which an provide detection.

Front end code::
index.html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-q/dWJ3kcmjBLU4Qc47E4A9kTB4m3wuTY7vkFJDTZKjTs8jhyGQnaUrxa0Ytd0ssMZhbNua9hE+E7Qv1j+DyZwA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        //socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });

</script>
<div><h1>Welcome to microphone streaming test</h1></div>

<video id="video" autoplay></video>

<script async src='../static/js/capture.js'></script>
```

Above is html file which get user devices mic to get audio using navigator

Capure.js

```
const video = document.getElementById('video');
debugger
function funSendsocketData(buffer){
    debugger;
    socket.emit('my event', {data: buffer});
}
function startup(){
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio:true,
    video:false
}).then(stream=>{
video.srcObject = stream;
recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);  
if(recorder.state === "recording"){
    recorder.stop();
}
else{
    recorder.start(5000);
    recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (async event => {

        if (typeof event.data === 'undefined') return;
        if (event.data.size === 0) return;   
        debugger;

        event.data.arrayBuffer().then(buffer =>
            funSendsocketData(buffer)
        );  
    }));
}



}).catch(console.error)
}
window.addEventListener('load',startup,false)
```

Captures the data for 5000ms or 5 sec and send blobover websocket connection to be saved or processed.

Flask backend

```
@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_message(data):
    #blob = requests.data
    import base64
    wav_file = open("temp.webm", "wb")
    decode_string = base64.b64decode(bytes(data['data']))
    with open("audioToSave.mp3", "wb") as fh:
        fh.write(decode_string)
    
    
    wav_file.write(decode_string)
```

Problem lies in backend as I cannot save the blob into the file to be processed by whisper . My blobs are correctly transferred to backend but I am unable to save the file as webm or wav or mp3.

Answer (score 0):

In the code, you are attempting to save the received blob data as an audio file in the Flask backend, but there seems to be an issue with saving the file in the desired format (webm, wav, or mp3). To resolve this issue, you can make the following modifications to your Flask backend code:

```
from flask import request

@socketio.on('my event')
def handle_message(data):
    # Extract blob data from the request
    blob_data = request.data

    # Save the blob data as a file
    with open("audioToSave.webm", "wb") as file:
        file.write(blob_data)

    # Perform further processing with the saved file
    # ...
```

By using the request object from Flask, you can access the raw data sent in the request and directly save it to a file. In this example, the blob data is saved as "audioToSave.webm" in the current working directory. You can modify the filename and path as per your requirements.

Comment: blob_data = request.data is empty when i modified the code

Comment: but i do have data in data variable. I think request will alway be empty because I am transmitting over websockets. I dont want to use http transfer.